# Delete backed up photos on Samsung S4 mini

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, photos

How do I delete backed up photos from my gallery (Samsung S4 mini).

Please note:  I took photos with my phone camera.  Those photos were uploaded to Google maps.  Once they were uploaded I deleted the photos. But those photos still show in gallery.  It won't let me delete it.  When I click on the photos there is no "delete icon (dustbin)".  It gives an options to share the photos but not to delete them.  Please help.

Comment: You need to log into the Google photo app and delete them from there.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no option to delete, then they're already gone from your device. Google keeps a thumbnail available for you so that you can see the photo, share, etc., without taking up a ton of storage on your phone.

If you want them *really* gone, you'll need to go to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) and delete them from there. (Actually, they'll go into the Trash, where they'll be auto-deleted in 3 days, but they'll get removed from your photo gallery on your phone.)